# Show that this operator is Hermitian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, adjoint-operators

The operator is defined as followed: $\hat A = a|u_{1}\rangle\langle u_{1}| + b|u_{2}\rangle\langle u_{2}|$

$a)\qquad a = b = 1$

$b)\qquad a = i, b = -i$

Comment: Did you try taking an adjoint?

Comment: @CameronWilliams that's the problem, I don't know how to take the adjoint :/

Answer (score 2):

taking adjoint of $\ a|x\rangle\langle y|\ $ gives $\ a^*|y\rangle\langle x|\ $. And their adjoint of a sum (of ket-bra) is the sum of the adjoints